# Writing to a specific address with printf format string attack

Tags: c, gdb, printf

Let's say there is this code that takes in user input and is vulnerable to a format string attack:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char user_input[100];

    ...

    scanf("%s", user_input);
    printf(user_input); // vulnerable to attack

    return 0
}
```

Suppose I want to exploit the `printf` line to write to a specific address `0x41414141`.

Normally you can overwrite the value at an address if it is offsetted on the stack. For example giving the input `%5\$n` writes to the 5th argument, offsetted in the stack.

However if this address `0x41414141` is not offsetted on the stack, then how do I write to it?

There are multiple examples for this that say to pass in input such as `\x41\x41\x41\x41 %x %x %x %n` in which `%x %x %x` moves the `printf()`'s pointer towards the specified address stored in the format string. Apparently this ends up overwriting the value at the address `0x41414141`? If this truly does work, then how do I know what the address of the format string is? I don't know what to look for in gdb.

[(This idea was interpreted from the example in these notes)](https://web.ecs.syr.edu/%7Ewedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

> However if this address 0x41414141 is not offsetted on the stack, then how do I write to it?

There is *no such thing* as an address that is not "offsetted" off some other address on non-segmented architectures (i.e. most current OSes).

With a flat memory model, every address can be computed as some other address + (possibly very large) offset.

For example, if your current `sp == 0x7fffffffdc20`, and you want to write address `0x41414141`, then all you have to do is add offset `0xffff800041416521`, or subtract offset `0x7fffbebe9adf` to `sp`.

That said, it would be impractical to supply a long-enough string to `scanf`, so in order to overwrite a specific address, you first corrupt some local pointer to point to the desired address, and then arrange to write through that pointer. In other words, you need to chain together multiple attacks.

Comment: "you first corrupt some local pointer to point to the desired address, and then arrange to write through that pointer" - this is something I've been trying to do but I don't understand how to do it with a format string input.